# Bitwise NOT in ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, math, operators

I have a formula in JS that uses the bitwise NOT operator.

```
~~(n/m + 0.5) * m;
```

How do I write the same expression in ruby? There is no bitwise NOT operator in ruby.

Comment: There is a bitwise NOT operator in ruby:  ~200  #=> -201 http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the same expression in Ruby would be `(n/m + 0.5).to_i * m`, or, alternatively, `Integer(n/m + 0.5) * m`.

It looks like the doubled bitwise complement there is really being used to truncate the decimal part of the calculation, in order to compute the nearest *n* such that *n* is a multiple of *m*.  (In another language, I would say *"convert to integer"*, but Javascript has a unified arithmetic type.)

*Update:* [Mladen Jablanović](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82592/mladen-jablanovic) suggests a cast, and yes, if both *m* and *n* are Fixnum, it's needed. In Ruby *1 / 3* is *0* but in JS it's *0.333...*  Here is a refined suggestion:

```
(n.to_f / m).round * m
```

Comment: yes, that's exactly the case. it would be probably better to avoid this by doing n|0 (in js, I don't know ruby)

Comment: Oh and I believe that `(n/m + 0.5).to_i` could be written as `(n/m).ceil`. Also, n and m could both be integers, so it could be wise to cast one of them to float before division.

Comment: Good point on the cast. With respect to `.ceil`, that would always round up. How about `.round`?

Comment: Well, `+0.5` is also there for rounding up, isn't it?

Comment: All I meant was, *1.4.round => 1* and *(1.4 + 0.5).to_i* and also *Integer(1.4 + 0.5)* both => 1; but *1.4.ceil => 2*.

Answer (score 7):

won't this help? http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operators#Ruby_Bitwise_Operators

~ Bitwise NOT (Complement)

Comment: Although answering the exact question asked is always good, it's also always a good idea to take a glance at the fundamental issue...